# Thumbnail for a Point - ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, thumbnail

I have a .csv that I have displayed as XY data on the map, using Arc Pro's XY Table to Point tool. There are 40 points.

I have 40 .pngs of graphs that correspond to each point. I'd like to be able to select a point and display a thumbnail of the graph in the pop-up window. Is this possible?

I have looked at:

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/metadata/create-a-thumbnail.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_E4B2309C5D204D97BC104463730F1F8A

and have tried going to View tab -> importing thumbnail, but that has not lead to any success.

Answer (score 2):

In ArcGIS Pro, a **thumbnail** refers to the small image which appears in the item's metadata in the catalog, and, if published, in the item's content page of a portal.

[image: thumbnail of map]

From your description, you want to include your images in the point's pop-up. There are a couple ways to do this.

#### 1. File Path in Pop-up Image

*Requirement: the points layer must have some attribute which corresponds to your image file names.*

Right-click the layer in the **Contents** panel, then select **Configure Pop-ups**. From here, you can choose to include an image in the popup. Edit the image element, and you will see a **URL** text field. This field can take a per-feature attribute as well as static text. You would enter something like this:

`directory/some_folder/{file_name_attribute}.png`

This works equally well for images hosted online, and can follow relative file paths as well. This has the benefit of being quick and easy, but then you're managing a separate folder of files, and you'll have to keep the filename attribute and the actual filenames synced manually.

#### 2. Attachments

*Requirement: The points layer must be within a geodatabase of some kind.*

Run the **Enable Attachments** GP tool, found in the **Data Management** toolbox. This adds an attachment table and relationship to the geodatabase so that your files can be linked to individual features in your layer.

Once you have attachments enabled, an **Attachments** tab will be available in the **Attributes** panel, where you can add/remove files for each point.

According to the [Pro documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/mapping/navigation/pop-ups.htm):

> By default, all attachments that are of type=image are included in the pop-up.

The obvious downside here is that images need to be added to your features one at a time, but the benefit is that your data are all in one location, and you do not need to maintain a separate folder or filename attribute.